# ASP WebMail: Set up SMTP authentication?

Tags: asp.net, email, razor, smtp, webmatrix

I'm developing web pages using Razor C# language in WebMatrix. I have a hosted website, I'm trying to incorporate an email system into it.

As per [this article on WebMail](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/webpages_ref_webmail.asp) I have set up the WebMail settings in my _AppStart.cshtml page. I've got my settings from my service provider. He's provided me a sample code using CDO object:

```
    dim config, sch     
    set config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    sch = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"

    with config.Fields
        .item(sch & "sendusing") = 2 ' cdoSendUsingPort
        .item(sch & "smtpserver") = "myserver"
        .item(sch & "smtpserverport") = 25
        .item(sch & "smtpusessl") = False
        .item(sch & "smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60           
        .item(sch & "smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic auth
        .item(sch & "sendusername") = "myemail@email.com"
        .item(sch & "sendpassword") = "password"
        .update
    end with

    Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")

    With myMail
        .Configuration = config
        .Subject = Request.Form("txtSubject")
        .From = Request.Form("txtFrom")
        .To = Request.Form("txtTo")
        .TextBody = Request.Form("txtMessage")
        Call .Send()
    End With
```

As you can see the above code is made in CDO. I'm trying to use the WebMail in Razor. The only point where I'm stuck is that my email server is not SSL but requires basic auth. I can't find any authentication setting in WebMail. How do I set the SMTP authentication in WebMail? This is my current code:

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "myserver";
WebMail.SmtpPort = 25;
WebMail.EnableSsl = false;
WebMail.UserName = "myemail@email.com";
WebMail.Password = "password";
WebMail.From = "Support <myemail@email.com>";
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example in c#. The Smtp class takes username password.

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("emailfrom","emailto");


        mail.From = new MailAddress("emailfrom");
        mail.Subject = txtsbjct.Text;
        string Body = txtmsg.Text;
        mail.Body = Body;

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "localhost"; 
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
      ("youremail", "yourpassword");
```

Comment: I've seen that code on other places, just want to clarify something... doesn't WebMail class support smtp auth? is it a must that I switch to the above code in order to use smtp auth?

Comment: I've just tried your solution and it works. So I'm going to stick to this now. Thanks!

Comment: Yes - WebMail supports basic authentication. I believe the problem you had was with the From address as I posted in my other comment. The WebMail helper is a simple wrapper around System.Net.Mail, which is what the code above is an example of.

Answer (score 1):

Basic authentication with mail servers usually consists of providing a user name and password. You set those using the `WebMail.UserName` and `WebMail.Password` properties.

By the way, your provider has given you sample code for sending mail using CDO in classic ASP. It is of no use to you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Well this is why I was asking a question here. My service provider has given me a code that I don't need. I've actually tried that code on classic asp and it works, means that I DO need smtp auth. You can see that I've already specified username and password on webmail, but still webserver throws exception by saying 'SMTP authentication required.'. I believe the SMTP auth (basic auth) needs to be set on WebMail to make it useful on my server.. question is How?

Comment: You should change the WebMail.From value to just an email address.

Comment: But this works like this as well. By setting `WebMail.From = "Support <myemail@email.com>";` I can set the title (caption) of the email address who's sending this email.

Comment: Hmm.. perhaps they updated that in version 2. I'm sure it would only accept an email address in v 1.