# Setting up Outgoing Email settings in Webmatrix

Tags: email, razor, webmatrix

I have been trying to set up the e-mail authentication using the following:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterGoogleClient();

WebMail.SmtpServer = "stmp.gmail.com";
WebMail.SmtpPort = 465;
WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
WebMail.UserName = "username@gmail.com";
WebMail.Password = "mypassword";
WebMail.From = "username@gmail.com";
```

On the page to send instructions for lost passwords the following code calls the settings above. However, It gives me a message that the email has been sent but nothing gets to my inbox, am I doing this wrong?

```
bool passwordSent = false;
var resetToken = "";
var email = Request.Form["email"] ?? Request.QueryString["email"];

// Setup validation
Validation.RequireField("email", "The email address field is required.");

if (IsPost) {
    AntiForgery.Validate();
    // validate email
    bool isValid = true;
    if (Validation.IsValid()) {
        if (WebSecurity.GetUserId(email) > -1 && WebSecurity.IsConfirmed(email)) {
            resetToken = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(email); // Optionally specify an
 expiration date for the token
        } else {
            passwordSent = true; // We don't want to disclose that the user does not exist.
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    if (isValid) {
        var hostUrl = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);
        var resetUrl = hostUrl + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Account/PasswordReset?resetToken=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resetToken));
        WebMail.Send(
            to: email,
            subject: "Please reset your password", 
            body: "Use this password reset token to reset your password. The token is: " + resetToken + @". Visit <a href=""" + HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(resetUrl) + @""">" + resetUrl + "</a> to reset your password."
        );
        passwordSent = true;
    }
}
}

<hgroup class="title">
<h1>@Page.Title.</h1>
<h2>Use the form below to reset your password.</h2>
</hgroup>

@if (!WebMail.SmtpServer.IsEmpty()) {
<p>
    We will send password reset instructions to the email address associated with your account.
</p>

if (passwordSent) {
    <p class="message-success">
        Instructions to reset your password have been sent to the specified email address.
    </p>
}

<form method="post">
    @AntiForgery.GetHtml()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(excludeFieldErrors: true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Password Reset Instructions Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li class="email">
                <label for="email" @if (!ModelState.IsValidField("email")) {<text>class="error-label"</text>}>Email address</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="@email" disabled="@passwordSent" @Validation.For("email") />
                @Html.ValidationMessage("email")
            </li>
        </ol>
        <p class="form-actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Send instructions" disabled="@passwordSent" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
} else {
<p class="message-info">
   Password recovery is disabled for this website because the SMTP server is 
   not configured correctly. Please contact the owner of this site to reset 
   your password.
</p>
}
```

I have read this question: [ASP WebMail: Set up SMTP authentication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12455383/asp-webmail-set-up-smtp-authentication) but I don't know how I would make the form use the settings on that page and not the ones provided by Webmatrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line

```
WebMail.SmtpServer = "stmp.gmail.com";
```

should it be "smtp.gmail.com" ?